# JPA Query returns "No value specified for parameter 3" but all parameters are given

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a Query to return a map with some IN clauses that only append to the query string when Set is not empty.

This is my method

```
public List<Object> findByFilter(String nome, DemandaStatus status, Set<Estado> estados, Set<Cidade> cidades, Set<Set<DemandaCategoria>> categorias, Set<Set<DemandaSubCategoria>> subCategorias) {

       String sqlString = "SELECT new map(d.nmDemanda as nmDemanda, d.dsDemanda as dsDemanda, d.vlDemanda as vlDemanda) "
            + "FROM Demanda as d ";
            sqlString = estados.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "JOIN d.estado estados ";
            sqlString = cidades.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "JOIN d.cidade cidades ";
            sqlString = categorias.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "JOIN d.categorias categorias ";
            sqlString = subCategorias.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "JOIN d.subCategorias subs ";

            sqlString = sqlString + "WHERE 1=1 ";

            sqlString = nome == null ? sqlString : sqlString + "AND d.nmDemanda = :nome ";
            sqlString = status == null ? sqlString : sqlString + "AND d.status = :status ";
            sqlString = estados.isEmpty() ? sqlString :  sqlString + "AND d.estado IN :estados ";
            sqlString = cidades.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "AND d.cidade IN :cidades ";
            sqlString = categorias.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "AND d.categorias IN :categorias ";
            sqlString = subCategorias.isEmpty() ? sqlString : sqlString + "AND d.subCategorias IN :subs ";

        Query query = em.createQuery(sqlString);

        query = nome == null ? query : query.setParameter("nome", nome);
        query = status == null ? query : query.setParameter("status", status);
        query = estados.isEmpty() ? query : query.setParameter("estados", estados);
        query = cidades.isEmpty() ? query : query.setParameter("cidades", cidades);
        query = categorias.isEmpty() ? query : query.setParameter("categorias", categorias);
        query = subCategorias.isEmpty() ? query : query.setParameter("subs", subCategorias);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

As I am trying with no "Estados" or "Cidades", this is the sqlString result

```
SELECT

new map(d.nmDemanda as nmDemanda, d.dsDemanda as dsDemanda, d.vlDemanda as vlDemanda)

FROM

Demanda as d JOIN d.categorias categorias JOIN d.subCategorias subs 

WHERE 1 = 1 

AND d.nmDemanda = :nome

AND d.status = :status

AND d.categorias IN :categorias

AND d.subCategorias IN :subs
```

And the query parameters are those 4, too.

This works fine (or seems to) and creates the Query as intended, as well as the Parameters, but I'm getting a "No value specified for parameter 3 (or other values here, when I pass more Sets in the parameter)".

Comment: Not sure but the syntax of seems not correct: `JOIN ... ON` instead of `JOIN ...`